# Address already in use error

Tags: networking, tcp

When you start a program to listen on a TCP socket then kill the program, sometimes (but not always) you get an error like "address already in use" when you try to listen on the socket again for the next few mins. The proc is killed with ctrl-c. I use linux.

I think this has something to do with a TCP connection being stuck in the CLOSE_WAIT state, but am not 100% sure. Why exactly do I get the "address already in use" error?

Also, why does this only sometimes happen?

Comment: Which process is it that you're killing? Are you killing it gracefully or with a -9?

Comment: Is there an actual question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to serverfault.com! Unfortunately, your question is rather unclear. Please include some more detail (OS, application), and make it into an actual question. Otherwise your question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in IP stacks that prevents a process to reopen a socket in listening mode too fast (that's a 2 minutes wait I think). Most of today programs remove this feature when they create a socket by using the SO_REUSEADDR flag when they create a socket.
Maybe your program doesn't using this flag?

Comment: it doesn't, but I believe I have run into this problem before using the flag after being told it wouldn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using netstat to see the state of the port or lsof -i: after you kill it to see what programs are still using the port if any.

Answer (score 0):

In which language are you writing ?

If you are writing in C, propably you need to check setsockopt() or better, select().

There are the functions to make the socket reusable , as being said.